# Library to play and create AI for "Connect Four"

Tags: c#, library, connect-four

I am looking for some advice to this code I made, which enables a fellow programmer to create his own AI for Connect Four whilst not really having to code the game itself.

Match class

```
public sealed class Match
{
    public const int cWidth = 7;
    public const int cHeight = 6;
    private static Random Random = new Random();

    private int _currentTurn;
    private List<BasePlayer> _players;
    private bool _isGameOver; 
    private Disc[,] _discs;
    internal Disc[,] Discs => _discs;
    internal BasePlayer CurrentPlayer { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }
    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public Disc RecentDisc { get; internal set; }

    public bool IsPositionWithinBoundries(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x < 0 || x >= Width)
            return false;
        if (y < 0 || y >= Height)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public bool IsRowValidMove(int x)
    {
        if (!IsPositionWithinBoundries(x, 0))
            return false;

        for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            if (_discs[x, y] == null)
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    public int GetColumnHeight(int x)
    {
        if (!IsPositionWithinBoundries(x, 0))
            return -1;

        int y = 0;
        for (; y < Height; y++)
            if (_discs[x, y] == null)
                return y;

        return y;
    }

    public Disc GetDiscAt(int x, int y)
    {
        if (!IsPositionWithinBoundries(x, y))
            return null;

        return _discs[x, y];
    }

    public Disc GetLastDiscInColumn(int x)
    {
        var y = GetColumnHeight(x);
        return GetDiscAt(x, y - 1);
    }

    public static Match CreateMatch(BasePlayer player1, BasePlayer player2)
    {
        return CreateMatch(player1, player2, cWidth, cHeight);
    }

    public static Match CreateMatch(BasePlayer player1, BasePlayer player2, int width, int height)
    {
        if (player1 == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(BasePlayer) + "1 is null");
        if (player2 == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(BasePlayer) + "2 is null");

        if (width < 1)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(width) + "1 is null");
        if (height < 1)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(BasePlayer) + "2 is null");

        return new Match(player1, player2, width, height);
    }

    public void StartMatch()
    {
        if (_isGameOver)
            return;

        for (;;)
        {
            _isGameOver = true; 
            foreach (var player in _players)
            {

                _currentTurn++;
                if (CheckGridFull())
                {
                    EndGame("Draw - Grid is filled");
                    return;
                }

                CurrentPlayer = player;
                CurrentPlayer.PlanMove();
                DoMove(CurrentPlayer);

                if (CheckWin())
                {
                    EndGame(CurrentPlayer.Name + " wins");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool CheckWin()
    {
        if (CheckDirectionsForDisc(RecentDisc))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    private bool CheckGridFull()
    {
        for (int x = Width - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            for (int y = Height - 1; y >= 0; y--)
            {
                if (GetDiscAt(x, y) == null)
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private bool CheckDirectionsForDisc(Disc disc)
    {
        return
            CheckDirectionForDisc(disc, EDirection.Diagonal) ||
            CheckDirectionForDisc(disc, EDirection.Vertical) ||
            CheckDirectionForDisc(disc, EDirection.Horizontal);
    }

    private bool CheckDirectionForDisc(Disc disc, EDirection direction)
    {
        var streak = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var x = disc.X + i * (direction.GetOffsetX());
            var y = disc.Y + i * (direction.GetOffsetY());
            var curDisc = GetDiscAt(x, y);
            if (curDisc != null && curDisc.Owner == disc.Owner)
                streak++;
            else
                break;
        }

        for (int i = -1; i > -4; i--)
        {
            var x = disc.X + i * (direction.GetOffsetX());
            var y = disc.Y + i * (direction.GetOffsetY());
            var curDisc = GetDiscAt(x, y);
            if (curDisc != null && curDisc.IsMine())
                streak++;
            else
                break;
        }

        return streak >= 4;
    }

    internal void EndGame(String message)
    {
        PrintField();
    }

    private void PrintField()
    {
        for (int y = Height - 1; y >= 0; y--)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
            for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
            {
                {
                    var disc = GetDiscAt(x, y);
                    if (disc == null)
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("-");
                    else if (disc.Owner == _players[0])
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("X");
                    else
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("0");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    internal void DoMove(BasePlayer player)
    {
        var y = GetColumnHeight(player.NextColumn);

        if (IsPositionWithinBoundries(player.NextColumn, y))
            Disc.CreateDisc(this, player.NextColumn, y);
    }

    private Match(BasePlayer player1, BasePlayer player2, int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width; 
        Height = height;
        _discs = new Disc[Width, Height];
        player1.Match = this;
        player2.Match = this;
        _players = new List<BasePlayer>();

        //var swapPlayers = Random.NextDouble() >= 0.5;
        _players.Add(player1);
        //if (swapPlayers)
        _players.Add(player2);
        //else
        //    _players.Insert(0, player2);
    }
}
```

BasePlayer which library users would have to extend

```
public abstract class BasePlayer
{
    public Match Match { get; internal set; }
    internal String Name { get; private set; }

    private int _nextRow = 0;
    public int NextColumn
    {
        get { return _nextRow; }
        protected set
        {
            //if(Match.IsRowValidMove(row))
            _nextRow = value;
        }
    }

    public abstract void PlanMove();
    public abstract void Initialize();
}
```

Disc

```
public sealed class Disc
{
    private Match _match;

    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
    internal BasePlayer Owner { get; }

    internal static Disc CreateDisc(Match match, int x, int y)
    {
        if (match == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Match));
        if (match.CurrentPlayer == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(match.CurrentPlayer) + " == null");
        if (!match.IsPositionWithinBoundries(x, y))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("x and y out of boundries");
        if (!match.IsRowValidMove(x))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("x exceeds row");
        if (match.GetDiscAt(x, y) != null)
            throw new ArgumentException("position already occupied");

        return new Disc(match, x, y, match.CurrentPlayer);
    }

    private Disc(Match match, int x, int y, BasePlayer owner)
    {
        _match = match;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Owner = owner;
        match.Discs[x, y] = this;
        match.RecentDisc = this; 
    }

    public bool IsMine()
    {
        return _match.CurrentPlayer == Owner;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Owner.Name + " " + base.ToString();
    }
}
```

enums

```
internal enum EDirection
{
    Horizontal, Vertical, Diagonal
}

internal static class EDirectionExtension
{
    internal static int GetOffsetX(this EDirection direction)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case EDirection.Horizontal:
            case EDirection.Diagonal:
                return 1;
            case EDirection.Vertical:
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    internal static int GetOffsetY(this EDirection direction)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case EDirection.Vertical:
            case EDirection.Diagonal:
                return 1;
            default:
            case EDirection.Horizontal:
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought of creating King of the Hill challenges for [codegolf.se]? This is the sort of thing you need to be able to do to create one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was actually a thing I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Few notes :

### Optional parameters vs multiple overloads

You can use optional parameters to avoid unnecessary method overloading

> ```
> public static Match CreateMatch(BasePlayer player1, BasePlayer player2)
> {
>     return CreateMatch(player1, player2, cWidth, cHeight);
> }
>
> public static Match CreateMatch(BasePlayer player1, BasePlayer player2, int width, int height)
> {
>     if (player1 == null)
>         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(BasePlayer) + "1 is null");
>     if (player2 == null)
>         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(BasePlayer) + "2 is null");
>
>     if (width < 1)
>         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(width) + "1 is null");
>     if (height < 1)
>         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(BasePlayer) + "2 is null");
>
>     return new Match(player1, player2, width, height);
> }
> ```

You can shorten that to a single method

```
public static Match CreateMatch(BasePlayer player1, BasePlayer player2, int width = cWidth, int height = cHeight)
{
    if (player1 == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(BasePlayer) + "1 is null");
    if (player2 == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(BasePlayer) + "2 is null");

    if (width < 1)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(width) + "1 is null");
    if (height < 1)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(BasePlayer) + "2 is null");

    return new Match(player1, player2, width, height);
}
```

### Ternary operator instead of short if/else

Single return statements based on the if condition can be shorten to one line using the ternary operator

> ```
> public Disc GetDiscAt(int x, int y)
> {
>     if (!IsPositionWithinBoundries(x, y))
>         return null;
>
>     return _discs[x, y];
> }
> ```

Can become

```
public Disc GetDiscAt(int x, int y)
{
    return !IsPositionWithinBoundries(x, y) ? null : _discs[x, y];
}
```

Or even shorter using expression body

```
public Disc GetDiscAt(int x, int y) => !IsPositionWithinBoundries(x, y) ? null : _discs[x, y];
```

### Single return statement instead of if/else in boolean functions

> ```
> public bool IsPositionWithinBoundries(int x, int y)
> {
>     if (x < 0 || x >= Width)
>         return false;
>     if (y < 0 || y >= Height)
>         return false;
>
>     return true;
> }
> ```

Since the function is of type `bool` you can directly return an if statements instead of doing the checks manually :

```
public bool IsPositionWithinBoundries(int x, int y) => x >= 0 && x < Width && y >= 0 && y < Height;
```

Also here

> ```
> private bool CheckWin()
> {
>     if (CheckDirectionsForDisc(RecentDisc))
>         return true;
>
>     return false;
> }
> ```

Can become

```
private bool CheckWin() => CheckDirectionsForDisc(RecentDisc);
```

### Redundancy in your code

```
internal static int GetOffsetX(this EDirection direction)
{
    switch (direction)
    {
        case EDirection.Horizontal:
        case EDirection.Diagonal:
            return 1;
        case EDirection.Vertical:
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

internal static int GetOffsetY(this EDirection direction)
{
    switch (direction)
    {
        case EDirection.Vertical:
        case EDirection.Diagonal:
            return 1;
        default:
        case EDirection.Horizontal:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

In both switch-cases you have all of the enum values + an extra case `default` which is impossible to happen in the current state as you are manually checking each case. If you were planning to make this more extensible, this is not the way, the user will still need to go in here and add the new case himself.

You can shorten those to one line using the ternary operator

```
internal static int GetOffsetX(this EDirection direction)
{
    return direction == EDirection.Horizontal || direction == EDirection.Diagonal ? 1 : 0;
}

internal static int GetOffsetY(this EDirection direction)
{
    return direction == EDirection.Vertical || direction == EDirection.Diagonal ? 1 : 0;
}
```

You have some unused variables

> ```
> public sealed class Match
> {
>     private static Random Random = new Random();
>
>     private int _currentTurn;
> }
> ```

Both `Random` and `_currentTurn` are left unused, you can simply remove them.

Some of your properties can be even more restrictive :

> ```
> public int Width { get; private set; }
> public int Height { get; private set; }
> ```

Can become readonly properties as you are giving them value only in the constructor

```
public int Width { get; }
public int Height { get; }
```

In your `BasePlayer` class you have this weird property

> `internal String Name { get; private set; }`

It's value is never set but it has a `private set` which means that any derived class (if any) wont be able to set this value you might consider making it a readonly property and provide an example constructor for your derived classes :

```
internal String Name { get; }

protected BasePlayer(string name)
{
    Name = name;
}
```

### Auto properties

> ```
> private int _nextRow = 0;
> public int NextColumn
> {
>     get { return _nextRow; }
>     protected set
>     {
>         _nextRow = value;
>     }
> }
> ```

First off it's kinda weird to have a property called `NextColumn` with a backing field called `_nextRow` ? Those are 2 different things, usually the backing field has the same name as the property but instead it start with small letter rather than a big one.

But more importantly you don't really need a backing field here, you can convert that to auto-property :

```
public int NextColumn { get; protected set; } = 0;
```

In your `Match` class you can do the same :

> ```
> private Disc[,] _discs;
> internal Disc[,] Discs => _discs;
> ```

Can become :

```
internal Disc[,] Discs { get; }
```

### Collection/object initializer

In your `Match` method :

> ```
> private Match(BasePlayer player1, BasePlayer player2, int width, int height)
> {
>     _players = new List<BasePlayer>();
>
>     _players.Add(player1);
>     _players.Add(player2);
> }
> ```

You can populate the list a lot easily using the collection intializer it provides :

```
private Match(BasePlayer player1, BasePlayer player2, int width, int height)
{
    _players = new List<BasePlayer> {player1, player2};
}
```

### Empty `for` loop vs `while(true)`

I'm pretty sure that there is no performance difference but I prefer having a `while(true)` loop instead of an empty `for (;;)` loop.

### Using the C#' aliases

And lastly a minor note I personally prefer using the C#' alias e.g

`string` instead of `String`

`short` instead of `Int16`

Comment: The `for (;;)` idiom has generally won out over `while (true)` because compilers generally issue a spurious warning about the loop condition being constitutively true for the latter, but not for the former. (Besides the fact that K&R originally recommended the use of `for` here.) But the C# compiler, as far as I can remember, doesn't generate such a warning for `while (true)`, so there's little argument against breaking the long-standing tradition in C-derived languages in favor of readability. (And no, *absolutely* no performance difference between the two. Both are identical in the IL.)

Answer (score 1):

[Do not use Hungarian notation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx): `cWidth`, `cHeight`. (And why are those `public`?)

---

I think this is an error:

```
    if (height < 1)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(BasePlayer) + "2 is null");
```

Shouldn't that be `nameof(height)`?

The rest of the exception message is also wrong of course: `"2 is null"`. A similar error appears just above it: `"1 is null"`. It looks like you copy-pasted the earlier checks for `player1` and `player2` and didn't change everything that was necessary.

---

`CheckGridFull()` doesn't convey that it returns a `bool`. Name it `IsGridFull()`. (Also, is looping through all coordinates in your grid efficient?)

Same for `CheckDirectionForDisc()`.

Comment: cWidth and cHeight are public as they are the defaultsize of the common ConnectFour and are the defaultsize when using the CreateOverload without a size.

Comment: I am not quiet convinced that using plane Pascal is proper for constants.

Renaming methods I do agree. While I do think the looping is done properly without doing too much calculations due to early escapes

Comment: @Kay Whether you're convinced Pascal is "proper" is kind of irrelevant given that you presumably have no impact on creating the standards.

Comment: If you made the constants private, @kay, you could use whatever naming convention you wanted. :-) Microsoft's guidelines specifically grant you the ability to decide on your own naming convention for private objects. But as long as they're going to be public, you want to follow the recommendations. Think about `Int32.MaxValue`.